# Can we change InterfaceOrientations from SKScene in spritekit?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, sprite-kit

In my spritekit game has more than one level. Some of the level are in landscape mode and some of are in portrait mode. Since the first level is in the landscape mode so when I call the first SKScene I set up the viewcontroller as

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

But when I want load my second scene which would be in portrait mode it shows in landscape mode. Now how do I change the orientation from landscape to portrait in the second level. There is only one view controller in my game.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to change the orientation of the device from code.
You could tell the users to rotate their device for the next (or current) level and handle accordingly.

Make sure your application supports multiple orientations and in the new scene, where you want to use portrait add the following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have run into this, and it's occurred to me that I might be able to just rotate the scene *until* the user rotates the device. Then it'll switch to portrait mode and I can rotate back.  That would seem to be more seamless then asking them to rotate it each time. Of course what I would be doing is prompting them without saying it :)

Comment: The other problem though, is that now you have to manage getting them to rotate back to landscape. Plus, if you don't want a given level to be played in portrait, how do you restrict that ? Since it's autorotate. what a pain....

Comment: The other option is to not allow autorotate. Rotate it yourself, and account for that in your game code in terms of how you layout the scene in terms of dimensions and handle input.